# How to change mindate and maxdate jquery datepicker from a select option

Tags: jquery, forms, html-select, jquery-ui-datepicker

there is a solution to change the dates (mindate and maxdate) in the jquery script, from select options?
Thank you for your help

```
<script src="//code.jquery.com/jquery-1.10.2.js"></script>
<script src="//code.jquery.com/ui/1.11.1/jquery-ui.js"></script>
<script src="js/datepicker-en.js"></script>
<script>
  jQuery(document).ready(function($) {
    $("#datepicker1").each(function() {
      $(this).datepicker({
        autoclose: true,
        minDate: new Date(2019, 03 - 1, 25), 
        maxDate: new Date(2019, 04 - 1, 25),
      });
    });
  });
</script>
```

Values to add or change by using select options (default option is empty, without any date range):

```
minDate: new Date(2019, 03 - 1, 25), 
maxDate: new Date(2019, 04 - 1, 25),
```

Selectbox example:

```
<select id="minmaxdate">
  <option value="">No date range</option>
  <option value="mindate 2019/01/25 maxdate 2019/04/25">from 2019/01/25 to 2019/04/25</option>
  <option value="mindate 2019/05/15 maxdate 2019/07/05">from 2019/05/15 to 2019/07/05</option>
  <option value="mindate 2019/09/18 maxdate 2019/04/25">from 2019/09/18 to 2019/04/25</option>
</select>
```

Answer (score 0):

To achieve this you could place the min/max dates in `data` attributes on the `option` elements. Then when a `change` event fires on the `select` you can update the `minDate` and `maxDate` options on the datepicker control to the new values.

Also note that you're calling `each()` on an `id` selector which is redundant as `id` attributes must be unique within the DOM.

```js
jQuery(function($) {
  $('#minmaxdate').change(function() {
    var $selected = $(this).find('option:selected');
    $('#datepicker1').datepicker('option', {
      minDate: new Date($selected.data('min')),
      maxDate: new Date($selected.data('max'))
    });
  });

  $("#datepicker1").datepicker({
    autoclose: true,
    minDate: new Date(2019, 2, 25),
    maxDate: new Date(2019, 3, 25),
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.10.2.js"></script>
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.11.1/jquery-ui.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.11.1/themes/smoothness/jquery-ui.css" />

<select id="minmaxdate">
  <option data-min="03-25-2019" data-maxdate="04-25-2019">No date range</option>
  <option data-min="01-25-2019" data-maxdate="04-25-2019">from 2019/01/25 to 2019/04/25</option>
  <option data-min="05-15-2019" data-maxdate="07-05-2019">from 2019/05/15 to 2019/07/05</option>
  <option data-min="09-18-2018" data-maxdate="04-25-2019">from 2018/09/18 to 2019/04/25</option>
</select>

<input type="text" id="datepicker1" />
```

Comment: Thank you @RoryMcCrossan . I tried your solution, but doesn't works. :(

Comment: Check the console for errors. As you can see in the example above, it works fine given the code you've shown in the question